# How to convert an element css to JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I let my users to change any attribute(location, color, and ...) of every element in a page before printing.

I'm looking for a way which user can store the new style sheet and restore it anytime later?

I've tried to parse `element.style`, but it doesn't return an array!
 Also `$(element).css()` doesn't work without any argument!

Comment: sample? convert document of this page!

Comment: No. how you want to store it ? which structure ?  what about style attribute ? who wins ? the inline style or the attribute ?  your question is not clear enough

Comment: I said it in the question! I want it in JSON format:)

Comment: Am I that unclear  ? :-) -- does your document contains unique IDS  for EVERY element? or it has also classes without id?  if so , how would you like to store it  ? '

Comment: none of them are requierd! I can access them with jQuery attr function!
I only want to store the changes to css file loaded styles! :)

Comment: if your elements recieve the styles via the `style` attribute you can `split(';')` that, then `split(':')`, `map(x->'"'+x+'"')`, `join(':')`, `join(',')` and wrap in `{}` to get a json string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with using a plugin for your task, try this plugin : https://github.com/reworkcss/css-parse

**Demo**:http://bililite.com/blog/blogfiles/cssparser/cssparsertest.php

Example:
CSS:

```
body {background: #eee;color: #888;}
```

Output:

```
{
    "type": "stylesheet",
        "stylesheet": {
        "rules": [{
            "type": "rule",
                "selectors": [
                "body"],
                "declarations": [{
                "type": "declaration",
                    "property": "background",
                    "value": "#eee"
            }, {
                "type": "declaration",
                    "property": "color",
                    "value": "#888"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Johan I found the correct answer! I only need to parse

```
window.getComputedStyle(element);
```

tnx everyone:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning custom styles to every element you could use unique style classes and a single stylesheet for the entire page (add it to the head, remembering the element or giving it a unique id) which contains your custom styles.

You can then enumerate the stylesheet through stylesheet.cssRules and build your custom json